# Initialized variable saying it is not initialized

Tags: java, initialization

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner numb = new Scanner(System.in);
    int r;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    int rr;
    int xx;
    int yy;
    int zz;
    boolean a1 = false;
    boolean a2 = false;
    boolean a3 = false;
    boolean a4 = false;
    System.out.println("Type four one's or zero's to convert a base 2 number to base 10. Please press enter between each one or zero: ");
    r = numb.nextInt();
    while (a1 == false) {
      if (r == 0) {
        a1 = true;
        rr = 0;
        } else if (r == 1) {
        a1 = true;
        rr = 8;
        } else {
        a1 = false;
        System.out.println("Please enter a 1 or a 0: ");
        r = numb.nextInt(); 
        } //end else
      } //end while
    x = numb.nextInt();
    while (a2 == false) {
      if (x == 0) {
        a2 = true;
        xx = 0;
        } else if (x == 1) {
        a2 = true;
        xx = 4;
        } else {
        a2 = false;
        System.out.println("Please enter a 1 or a 0: ");
        x = numb.nextInt(); 
        } //end else
      } //end while
    y = numb.nextInt();
    while (a3 == false) {
      if (y == 0) {
        a3 = true;
        yy = 0;
        } else if (y == 1) {
        a3 = true;
        yy = 2;
        } else {
        a3 = false;
        System.out.println("Please enter a 1 or a 0: ");
        y = numb.nextInt(); 
        } //end else
      } //end while
    z = numb.nextInt();
    while (a4 == false) {
      if (z == 0) {
        a4 = true;
        zz = 0;
        } else if (z == 1) {
        a4 = true;
        zz = 1;
        } else {
        a4 = false;
        System.out.println("Please enter a 1 or a 0: ");
        z = numb.nextInt();
        } //end else
      } //end while
      int a = rr + xx + yy + zz;
      System.out.println("You entered " + r + x + y + z + ", in base 10 that number is " + a);
    } //end main
} //end class Main
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this that would be greatly appreciated. The code gives an error when run, the error message shown is: "variable rr, xx, yy, zz might not have been initialized". I have tried many different things and can not get the code working with an equaling the outcome of rr + xx + yy + zz. Just started learning java so I'm not overly confident I am not just overlooking something I did wrong. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Those variables are declared, but not initialized. They have no value when you do `int a = rr + xx + yy + zz;`. What value do you expect `a` to have after that line?

Comment: I recommend you name your variables with meaningful names.

Comment: You might want to consider using arrays and loops, to avoid repeating essentially the same code.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah after looking that up that would definitely simplify my code quite a bit more. We have not yet been taught those in class. Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Taking your code into account:

```
int r; // You declared the variable [r] without initializing it with a valid integer value.

while (a1 == false) {
    if (r == 0) { 
    // It is semantically and syntactically wrong to compare the value of an...
    // ...undefined variable to a defined variable or a value.
        a1 = true;
        rr = 0;
    } else if (r == 1) {
        a1 = true;
        rr = 8;
    } else {
        a1 = false;

    System.out.println("Please enter a 1 or a 0: ");
    r = numb.nextInt(); 
    } //end else
  } //end while
x = numb.nextInt();
```

It is similar to comparing the amount of water in an empty bottle and a full one. It is not a wise comparison because the former does not even contain water.
I hope my analogy helps.

Comment: That makes a little more sense. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: It'd mean a lot to me if you could upvote the answer and accept it. Only if it helps you though.

Answer (score -1):

When you are intializing the variable assign it  to 0 this would do

Comment: Ok, thank you! Why does it need to be like this? Just curious so I can learn for the future.

Comment: @MichaelPennington It doesn't need to be like that. In fact, in your original code, if you had done that, `a` would have had a value of zero, which is not what you want.